# Struggling with prepared statements using the COM class

Tags: php, com, prepared-statement, adodb

I am not familiar with the COM class at all and I have not used PHP that much in a few years, so I am really struggling with this.  At this point, I am only trying reconfigure the code to prevent SQL injection.  There is a deadline to have this done shortly, so now I need to reach out for help.

Here is the original connection statement.

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$conn->open ("PROVIDER=MSOLEDBSQL;SERVER=".$servername.";UID=".$user.";PWD=".$pwd.";DATABASE=".$db);
```

I assumed I could use prepared statements or binding, however when I do, I get a “cannot pass parameter 2 by reference” error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE User=?";
$rs= $conn->Execute($sql,array($user));
Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in...
```

I also tried something similar to what is documented on the adodb.org page, with similar results.

```
$bindVars = array('$user');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Account WHERE User=?";
$rs = $conn->execute($sql,$bindVars);
Uncaught com_exception: Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server 
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

The errors I am getting makes it look like one of (or possibly both) is possible, but I cannot seem to find the right combination of parameters that will make this work.  Can one of these be configured to work?  If so, how?

If it is not possible, then I will try to reconfigure this for mysqli (they also have a MySQL database) and probably have to rewrite the entire site.  Here are a couple of snippets of the current code.  Does anyone have a good example of translating something like this to code that would work if I have to switch to using the MySQLi driver instead?

```
if ( (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) && (is_numeric($_SESSION['userid'])) ) {
    $item = isValidItem($_GET['item']);
    $enddate = strtotime($item->Fields['EndDate']->value);
    if (is_numeric($_POST['amount'])) { $_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['amount']; }
    if ((is_null($item) == false) && (isset($_SESSION['amount'])) && (isValidBid($item,$_SESSION['amount']))) {
        $highestbidder = $item->Fields['UserID']->value;
        
...

function isValidBid($item,$amount) {
$currentbid = $item->Fields['CurrentBid']->value;
$startdate = strtotime($item->Fields['StartDate']->value);
global $enddate;
if (time() > ($enddate - 300)) {
    if (($amount-$currentbid) < 50) {
        alert("Invalid bid amount");
        session_destroy();
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You are correct.  It is not mysqli.  I might have to convert this to mysqli though.  I hoped I could keep what was there in place for now.  The original developer is no longer with us.

Comment: The code works fine, other than it is vulnerable to SQL injection. That is my dilemma: I either need to find a way to make a prepared statement, or I will have to rewrite most of the code.  I have not been able to find a way to bind parameters to a sql statement.